# Javascript function won't stop running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a few modals that the user navigates between. The problem is that when a function starts from the user clicking a button, it won't stop, and it prevents the user from being able to close other modals.

```
$('#btnother1').click(function () {
pluscount = 1;
vfnumModal.style.display = "none";
vdscrollmodal.style.display = "block";
window.onclick = function windowclosebtn(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
    if (event.target == vdscrollmodal) {
        vdscrollmodal.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
}
})
```

For testing purposes it alerts me the target id once running. But after it closes the vdscrollmodal, it keeps alerting the target id. So then if this function starts running:

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("sidebutton").style.add = "blue";
document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.width = "100%";
document.getElementById("sidenavsub").style.width = "700px";
document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
window.onclick = function windowclose(event) {
    if (event.target == document.getElementById('Sidenav')) {
        closeNav();
    }
}
}
```

closeNav() does:

```
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("sidenavsub").style.width = "0";
}
```

The "windowclose" event doesn't fire. It keeps showing me the target id, which means the first "windowclosebtn" function is still running. How do I fix this? Putting return everywhere in the "windowclosebtn" seems to have no effect.

Comment: What does `closeNav()` do?

Comment: Added in edit. It just closes the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to assign a click event handler in another click event handler. This handler is never detached, so it keeps responding *to every click*, even after it did its job.

You should at least move the `alert` inside the `if` block, and replace it by the less obstructive `console.log`.

It would be even better if you would attach the click handler only once, and would rely on the tests made in that handler itself to see if something needs to be done. Something like this:

```
$('#btnother1').click(function () {
    pluscount = 1;
    vfnumModal.style.display = "none";
    vdscrollmodal.style.display = "block";
});

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebutton").style.add = "blue";
    document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("sidenavsub").style.width = "700px";
    document.getElementById("Sidenav").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

window.onclick = function windowclosebtn(event) {
    if (event.target == vdscrollmodal) {
        console.log(event.target.id);
        vdscrollmodal.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
    if (event.target == document.getElementById('Sidenav')) {
        closeNav();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Code is missing here.

But there is something which won't work as you expect.

```
window.onclick = function windowclose(event) {
    if (event.target == document.getElementById('Sidenav')) {
        closeNav();
    }
}
```

Having this inside your function won't just make it trigger only once, but any time (you are setting it to `window.`), even after the function has completed.

Make sure you are not doing the same with your `opennav`.

Comment: Added the closeNav() in the original post. So then should the window.onclick function be instantiated on page load?

Comment: @anesthetic it'll do the same after the `opennav` function has been called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't close it. That just shrinks it. You should probably try to add that click listener to the modal instead of the window.

Comment: I suppose that's more accurate. To the user it "closes" it. When triggered it works as intended. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't trigger the shrink event if the first window.onclick event is running